# Text wrapping in CurVe rubric entry name

Tags: spacing, cv, curve-class

I'm working on a LaTeX document using the CurVe package to create a rubric for displaying information. I want the rubric entry key values to wrap where specified, however, I'm struggling to find a way to achieve this.

Current look is below. I would like the June 2023 - Sept 2023 text to be wrapped and on different lines, as it  takes up too much horizontal space in the page.

[image: Not wrapped text image]

settings.sty:

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[longtable]
\WarningsOff[array]

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\raggedright

\RequirePackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment}
\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}


\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
   \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}
   

\headerscale{1}
%\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt}
%\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}


\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{1em}}

\keyalignment{r}
\rubricalignment{l}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%
  \hspace*{-2.5ex}
  \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
  \hspace*{1ex}%
}

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vskip\subrubricbeforespace{\@subrubricfont\hspace{3pt}#1}\par}

\defbibfilter{booksandchapters}{%
( type=book or type=incollection )
}

\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\mynames}[1]{\def\my@namelist{#1}}
\newtoggle{boldname}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \global\togglefalse{boldname}%
  \foreach \my@fname / \my@gname in \my@namelist {%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\my@fname}}
                 and
                 test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\my@gname}}}
      {\global\toggletrue{boldname}}{}%
  }%
  \iftoggle{boldname}{\textbf{#1}}{#1}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \global\togglefalse{boldname}%
  \foreach \my@fname / \my@gname in \my@namelist{%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\my@fname}}
                 and
                 test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\my@gname}}}
      {\global\toggletrue{boldname}\breakforeach}{}%
  }%
  \iftoggle{boldname}{\textbf{#1}}{#1}%
}


\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

emplyoment.tex:

```
\begin{rubric}{Employment History}
\entry*[June 2023 - Sept 2023]%
    \textbf{Lecturer.} Information Technology Department, School of Engineering, Science and Technology, XYZ College.
%
\entry*[June 2022 - Sept 2022]%
    \textbf{Lecturer.} Information Technology Department, School of Engineering, Science and Technology, XYZ College.
%
\end{rubric}
```

Comment: There's a problem: when copying your code, it won't and can't compile. So may I ask you to prune your code to a **very minimal version** and provide **all** information needed to make it run once copied? If in doubt: leave things out, like fany fonts etc. Less is more here. // As I read it, you follow the long example from Overleaf or similar, which may nt be a good approach. // BTW, did you use the geometry package to vary e.g. margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint, it's always good trying to understand the documentclass one is going to use, before doing fancy things ... or just copying them.

The answer to your wrapping question is in the [curve manual, p. 15, Q5](https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/curve/curve.pdf). It's also a good idea to follow [this introduction into this class](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-3/verna/verna.pdf).

To reproduce, just create these 4 files as a minimal example (`MWE`) and compile.

- define your own keyfont in the main's preamble `\makeatletter\let\mykeyfont\@keyfont\makeatother`
- as rubric's are using longtables, replace the entry by this AND watch the braces: `\entry*[\multicolumn{1}{@{}>{\mykeyfont}p{5mm}} {2004 - 2008}]...`
- as described in the manual, i.e. describing the trick used

**Main file tut2b.tex**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{curve}
\usepackage[nohead,hmargin=15mm,vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\leftheader{Doja Cat\\\texttt{doja@cat.com}\\xyz drive\\Somewhere}
\rightheader{1 husband\\2 kids\\8 grammies}
\photo[r]{bild.png}

\title{Assistant Professor}
\subtitle{She a lil rebel}

\titlealignment{r}

\rubricalignment{cl}


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\makeatletter\let\mykeyfont\@keyfont\makeatother

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 
 \makeheaders[t]
 \maketitle
 
 \makerubric{experience2}
 \makerubric{education1}
 
\end{document}
```

**experience2.tex**:

```
\begin{rubric}{Professional experience}
  \subrubric{Research}
    \entry*[2004 - \ldots] Meta programming

  \subrubric{Lectures}
    \entry*[2002 - \ldots] \textbf{Latex: an overview} (3 hours)
    \entry*[\multicolumn{1}{@{}>{\mykeyfont}p{5mm}} {2004 - 2008}] \lipsum[4]
\end{rubric}
```

**experience.tex**:

```
\begin{rubric}{Education}
  \subrubric{School}
  \text{\hspace{3mm} Some text to try.\par}
  \entry*[2000 - 2004] Schule des Lebens
\end{rubric}
```

**bild.png**:

[image: photo]

**Result**:

Please notice that the manual adjustment of **p{..}** in the `entry` is done only once, i.e. other (sub)rubrics may be misaligned.

[image: result]